# How to search certain text in all files in certain git tags/branches?

Tags: git

I am looking to search for a "certain text" in all the files within certain git tags/branches. What would be a good way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to look for that string *in the commit pointed by that reference* (e.g: the topmost commit of target branch, or the commit pointed by a specific tag), you can use `git grep` :

```
git grep -e "certain text" <branch or tag>

# you can specify several names in one go:
git grep -e "certain text" <br1> <br2> <tag3> --
```

check [`git help grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) for detailed options.

---

If you want to look for that string *in the history of a branch or a tag* (to see when it appeared, or how it was moved around the repository), you can use `git log -G <pattern>` :

```
# when combined with -G, --name-only and --name-status will filter the files
# and keep only the ones for which "certain text" is in the diff
git log --name-status -G "certain text" <branch or tag>
```

You can get the documentation for `-G` (and its companion `-S`) in [`git help log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt)